# How can I remove leading numbers from filenames using prename?

Tags: regex, perl

I have many files like these

```
0678 - Puzzle Series Vol. 5 - Slither Link (J).nds
0679 - Puzzle Series Vol. 6 - Illust Logic (J).nds
0680 - Puzzle Series Vol. 7 - Crossword 2 (J).nds
```

and would like remove the leading four digit numbers and the dash, so they become

```
Puzzle Series Vol. 5 - Slither Link (J).nds
Puzzle Series Vol. 6 - Illust Logic (J).nds
Puzzle Series Vol. 7 - Crossword 2 (J).nds
```

When I try with `prename` I get

```
$ prename -i 's/???? - (.+nds)/$1/' *nds
Quantifier follows nothing in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/? <-- HERE ??? - (.+nds)/ at (eval 1) line 1.
```

**Question**

Can someone see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Following command should remove leading 4 digits `prename 's/^\d{4} - //' *.nds`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`?` doesn't mean what you think it means. It means the previous atom is optional. For example `/^ab?\z/` matches `a` and `ab`.

Use `.` to match any character except a line feed. `/s` makes `.` any character, period.

```
s/.... - (.+nds)/$1/

s/.{4} - (.+nds)/$1/          # Readability improvement.

s/.{4} - (.+nds)/$1/s         # No need to prevent `.` from matching a LF.

s/^.{4} - (.+nds)/$1/s        # Better to anchor for readability if nothing else.

s/^\d{4} - (.+nds)/$1/s       # A bit more restrictive, and more self-documenting.

s/^\d+ - (.+nds)/$1/s         # Do we really need to check that there are exactly 4?

s/^\d+ - (.*)/$1/s            # No point in checking if `nds` is contained.

s/^\d+ - //
```

Comment: Can LF (LineFeeds?) appear in filenames?

Comment: Yes, LF means Line Feed (U+000A). Yes, file names on unix systems can technically contain anything but NUL (byte `00`) and `/` (the directory separator). (Windows is more restrictive.) Noone uses them intentionally, of course. I just prefer not excluding LF unless I have a reason to. Why spend time checking for line feeds for nothing? In other words, I use `/s` by default in patters with `.`, and I see omitting `/s` as intentionally checking for line feeds.